# linear algebra-norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why $ \|A\| = \|A^*\| $ in matrix ?
Suppose that A is a normal matrix.
I know  $ A^* = A^{-1} \det(A) $
and so $\|A^*\| = \|\det(A) A^{-1} \| \rightarrow \|A^*\|=\det(A) \|A^{-1}\|$
but I can't prove $\|A\| = \det(A)\|A^-1\|$
Thank you
sinod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the matrix 2-norm, $\|A\|=\|A^*\|$ for any $A$ no matter whether $A$ is normal or abnormal. If $A=USV^*$ is the SVD of $A$, $A^*=VSU^*$ is the SVD of $A^*$ so both $A$ and $A^*$ have the same singular values. So 
$$
\begin{split}
\color{red}{\|A\|_2^2}&=\rho(A^*A)=\rho(V^*S^TUU^*SV)=\rho(S^TS)=\color{red}{\sigma_\max^2(A)}\\&=\rho(SS^T)=\rho(USV^*VS^TU^*)=\rho(AA^*)=\color{red}{\|A^*\|_2^2}.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from the fact that if $A$ is a normal matrix, then for all vectors $\Vert Ax \Vert= \Vert A^*x \Vert$.

The proof is pretty simple using the scalar product $x \cdot y$. For all vectors you have:

$$\Vert Ax \Vert^2=Ax \cdot Ax=x \cdot A^*Ax=x \cdot AA^*x=x \cdot A^{**}A^*x=A^*x \cdot A^*x=\Vert A^*x \Vert^2$$

Because as $A$ is supposed to be normal: $A A^*=A^*A$, for all matrices you have the equality $A^{**}=A$. And $x \cdot A^*y = Ax \cdot y$ for all vectors $x,y$ by definition of the conjugate transpose matrix.